# How to decline job offer after considering commute?

Tags: job-offer, commute

I made a stupid mistake: a potential employer asked me if I am willing to commute. I told them yes, but I prefer the closer location. However, I received the job offer at the location that's further away. Now I regret it as I cannot commute for 30 miles given that I am in California and it will take me at least 2 hours back and forth.

How can I decline the job offer?

Comment: I recommend negotiating for the closer location, because after more research, you discovered that the commute isn't feasible. I commute 35 miles in California to my job daily. It's a bit of a pain, but very doable.

Comment: If it's a very good opportunity, other than the commute, and it's it's a good locality, then perhaps you could consider re-locating.

Comment: “I made a stupid mistake” — no you didn’t. You changed your mind. You’re allowed to do this.

Comment: Is "2 hours back and forth" the total for the day or the duration for one way (totalling 4 hours daily)?

Comment: Just tell them the truth. For example, "I just realize that it will take me at least 2 hours back and forth. So, I am sorry but I have to decline this offer".  If they really want you, then you can ask them if they would consider paying you more so that you can relocate (i.e., rent an apartment close to their company.)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to decline only for the commute reason and are open to joining them if your location is closer, then you can say something like this:

> Thanks for the offer. I was really looking forward to work with you but I am unable to travel 30 miles every day. While I mentioned I am open to commuting, I did indicate my preference to be closer. Thanks again for showing your confidence in me and I am sorry I cannot take this offer as of now.  I hope we get an opportunity to work together again in future.

You may be concerned that it will look like you are turning back on what you said during the interview but I think it is okay. Even if commute was not your concern, declining a job offer is kind of turning back because you did appear for interview and expressed your interest in working. This happens all the time.

Also, now you have clearly communicated to them what you want and they can decide if they want to change the location for you.

Comment: +1 Giving the reason also leaves open the possibility that the company may approach you later if they have a job that doesn't require the commute.

Comment: If the job offer was for $1 Million you'd probably be fine with the commute. So evaluating the entire offer and then declining is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Chris A lot of people probably wouldn’t be, actually, especially if they value things like spending time with their family.

Answer (score 13):

Don't give a reason unless you're hoping to turn it into a negotiation to change that reason.

In other words, if you'd be willing to accept based on a closer location, or partial work from home, or flexible schedules, or some other condition that eliminates the commute time, go ahead and explain that the commute is preventing you from accepting. **If you really want the job, you have nothing to lose by asking.**

If however you're not interested in the position and/or don't expect a negotiation to go in your favor, don't give a reason. You're under no obligation to do so, and **if you're sure you no longer want the job, you have nothing to gain by giving a reason.**

Comment: Why would he NOT want to leave open at least the possibility of taking the job if the commute issues were reduced? If he declines the job saying it's only because of the commute distance, then if the company opens an office in his home town they will probably contact him. If he declines without a reason they may not.

Comment: Sure, that might happen, though I suppose it would fall under my first paragraph, not my second. But maybe they'd also think, "well, he implied he'd be OK with a commute and now he's telling us he doesn't want one? That's shifty." Turning down an offer is similar to leaving an employer: generally, giving a reason is potentially giving them something to be upset at you about, and burning a bridge. Google can give you plenty of references backing up that it's generally not helpful to give "why I don't want to work for you" feedback unless there's a specific, realistic potential upside for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just say so and explain the reason.  You can say something like "after thinking about all of the details of the offer, I think the commute would be too difficult for me; I would be happy to accept the offer if I could work at the closer location, but unfortunately the farther location is too far for me".  If it's a large company (based on your description, if they have 2 offices within 30 miles of each other then it's probably a large company) they'll make it happen for you to work at the closer office.

I once had a similar experience where I was offered a job across the country with a large company.  I mentioned to them that I wasn't at a point in my life where relocating would be amenable for me, and as the company had an office locally in my city, if I could work at that office instead.  They made it happen.

Answer (score -1):

Say No.

You don't have to give a reason when declining a job offer, if they ask why you can easily just say "personal reasons" or you've had a better offer.

Even if you say you've reconsidered the travel and you've decided against it now.
So basically just decline it and that's it.

Comment: Why would he not want to give a reason? Giving a reason at least leaves open the possibility of the company addressing it, either now or if another opening comes up in the future.

Comment: Agreed with @DJClayworth. The only time you'd want to give a generic "no" is when the declining reason is something personal or offensive to the company. In this case, it's a very understandable reason, which might open the door to negotiating for part-remote or closer location if they want him enough.

Comment: Question says how to decline. Not how to negotiate, not how to improve the situation. To *Decline* You say no. Not once did OP say I want to see if they can change it